# Two activities in manifest

Tags: android

So I have two activities that I would like to run, the first being an activity that when button clicked changes the background. The second activity when middle imagebutton clicked, opens the camera, takes photo then places the image in the imagebutton. Currently only the MainActivity(camera activity) is working. I would like help if possible :).

EDIT:
The MyAndroidAppActivity IS NOT WORKING. Only the MainActivity is working. I would like help with making it so both activities work.
EDIT 2:
There isn't a crash, the second activity purely does not work, at all. It should change the background when I click the button, it does nothing.

MainActivity:
    package com.example.triptych4;

```
import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // label our logs "CameraApp3"
    private static String logtag = "CameraApp3";
    // tells us which camera to take a picture from
    private static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
    // empty variable to hold our image Uri once we store it
    private Uri imageUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // look for the button we set in the view
        ImageButton cameraButton = (ImageButton)
                findViewById(R.id.button_camera);
        // set a listener on the button
        cameraButton.setOnClickListener(cameraListener);


    }

    // set a new listener
    private OnClickListener cameraListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // open the camera and pass in the current view
            takePhoto(v);
        }
    };

    public void takePhoto(View v) {
        // tell the phone we want to use the camera
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        // create a new temp file called pic.jpg in the "pictures" storage area of the phone
        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "pic.jpg");
        // take the return data and store it in the temp file "pic.jpg"
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
        // stor the temp photo uri so we can find it later
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
        // start the camera
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // override the original activity result function
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // call the parent
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch(requestCode) {
        // if the requestCode was equal to our camera code (1) then...
        case 1:
            // if the user took a photo and selected the photo to use
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // get the image uri from earlier
                Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
                // notify any apps of any changes we make
                getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                // get the imageView we set in our view earlier
                ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_camera);
                // create a content resolver object which will allow us to access the image file at the uri above
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                // create an empty bitmap object
                Bitmap bitmap;
                try {
                    // get the bitmap from the image uri using the content resolver api to get the image
                    bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
                    // set the bitmap to the image view
                    imageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    // notify the user
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selectedImage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    // notify the user
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e(logtag, e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

MyAndroidAppActivity (change background activity)

```
package com.example.triptych4;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;
    ImageView image;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImage);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android3d);


            }


        });

    }



}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.triptych4"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MyAndroidAppActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Exactly where do you need help? You just told us that your Main Activity is working and did not tell us where you're having difficulty with.

Comment: The manifest is case-sensitive. Try changing `android.intent.category.Default` to `android.intent.category.DEFAULT`

Comment: Changed the Default to DEFAULT and it still doesn't work :/

Comment: what is the logcat when app crash? please share

Comment: What do you mean by **"doesn't work"**? Please be more specific.

Comment: Where you are calling intent for opening of `MyAndroidAppActivity`

Comment: <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

remove this in your second activity

Comment: @AhmadNawaz I have no intent, where would I place the intent? Can you add a comment where I would place the intent?

Comment: @Harrison when you want to open `MyAndroidAppActivity`?

Comment: @AhmadNawaz im fairly new to android development. Would I place an intent in my MainActivity? If so where abouts in the MainActivity? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Harrison if you don't know how to open activity then first you should follow and learn from some basic android tutorials.

Comment: I'm doing this for a product at my school. I would like to get this application out of the way so I can move on to creating a game that I will be spending a lot more time and effort on. If you could just show me how to open the activity quickly without me having to do a heap of research it would help me a heap :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `MainActivity` you are not opening `MyAndroidAppActivity` anywhere. First you have to call `MyAndroidAppActivity` intent. 
Use following code for opening `MyAndroidAppActivity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyAndroidAppActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

You can put a button openAcitvity in `MainActivity`

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openAcitivty);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyAndroidAppActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);
            }


        });
```

Comment: I'm very very new to android. Is it possible if you could copy the activities and show me where you would place the new lines of code? Whenever I place them in, I get a heap of errors. Thanks again :)

Comment: You can learn from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html how to open activity.

Answer (score 0):

Still, you did not open your second activity in your mentioned code

Write this line code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyAndroidAppActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

on image button click which starts your second activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use this intent

```
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```